# SearchTileBrush and SearchTyleHighlightedBrush is not recognized

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, mahapps.metro

[how to highlight tiles of MahApps.Metro on mouseover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447323/how-to-highlight-tiles-of-mahapps-metro-on-mouseover)

I have tried to use the code as suggested in the answer. However, SearchTileBrush and SearchTyleHighlightedBrush is not recognized in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define these brushes in Resources for yourself, `SearchTileBrush`/`SearchTyleHighlightedBrush` are names picked by the answerer, they are not system predefined colors.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SearchTileBrush" Color="Red" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SearchTyleHighlightedBrush" Color="Green" />

<Style x:Key="SearchTile" TargetType="mah:Tile">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SearchTileBrush}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SearchTyleHighlightedBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```